# Move position of a UIImageview

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to move the position of an image within a grid from a button, but comes up with "Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '() -> Void'" at the `=`.  Help would be much appreciated.

```
    @IBAction func testMoveRight(_ sender: Any) {
    UIImageView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: self.testShipPlace.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 5, width: 84, height: 47), completion: nil)
}
```

Note, the grid is part of the background image, not generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that you are attempting to pass a line of code for `animations` when it is expecting a closure.  You need to wrap that line of code in `{ }`:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { self.testShipPlace.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 5, width: 84, height: 47) }, completion: nil)
```

**Notes:**

- The error message comes from the fact that an assignment statement in Swift returns `()`, unlike other C-based languages which return the value being assigned. The `animations` argument is expecting a `() -> Void` closure which is a closure which takes no arguments and returns no values.
- `animate` is a class method on `UIView`, so it is typical to just call it on `UIView` and not on the subclass (like `UIImageView`).